# Slow dataframe write in red shift using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

Using [RedShift JDBC driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html) I wrote data frame in redshift and my code as below :

```
  def writeUsingJDBC(dataFrame: DataFrame, url: String, tableName: String) = {
  try {
    dataFrame.coalesce(100).write.mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .option("batchsize", 100000)
      .jdbc(url, tableName, property)
  } catch {
    case ex: Exception =>
      println("Error in writing data into redshift using JDBC driver: " + ex.getMessage)
  }
}
```

but above code does not work properly for writing 100000 records it takes 138 seconds my redshift cluster is `M3XLarge` 1 master and 3 core

Comment: you do not want to generate inserts like that into redshift - its too slow. https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshiftmay help,

Comment: I tried the given link but I have some issue in that please check this 
https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/392